# How to combine Language Server and Code Formatter?

Tags: syntax, formatting, highlight, text-alignment

I am new to VS code and I am using it to code for a custom macro language. There is a marketplace extension for the language syntax highlighting however this does not auto format / auto align the code. Can any offer a suggestion on how to get auto alignment working at the same time as the language server.

I have tried other extensions, for example the c++ (ms-vscode.cpptools) and this does the formatting / alignment but the syntax highlighting is not correct.

Thanks.